# TelnetExpect Reading Output from Stream in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, telnet, telnetlib

Good Morning,

I have been tasked with writing a program that locates the local port a MAC Address is registered to, and to do that I need to SSH and Telnet into Cisco devices and receive the output of the commands so I can parse it and decide what to do with the information.

So far I have the SSH connection and parsing done no problem thanks to Renci.SshNET. But I am having trouble with the Telnet, I set it up to use Telnetlib.dll and I know it works because I can do "show users" on the switch I'm connecting to and see that one of the vty lines are being occupied by my application. But in the application I'm writing all I get is the application freezing up, none of the buttons work, and I can't see the mouse when I hover over the window, so I'm guessing that the application isn't liking something at run-time.

The code I'm using, in VB.NET is:

```
    Using client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(host, 23)
        Dim tel As TelnetStream = New TelnetStream(client.GetStream)
        Dim buff(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        Dim result As String

        tel.SetRemoteMode(TelnetOption.Echo, False)

        Dim exp As Expector = New Expector(tel)

        exp.Expect("username: ")
        exp.SendLine(username)
        exp.Expect("password: ")
        exp.SendLine(password)
        exp.Expect(">")


        tel.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)

        result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff)



        MessageBox.Show(result)
    End Using
```

Telnetlib.dll include the definitions for the Expector, SendLine, Expect, and TelnetStream.

I did some debugging and found that it freezes when it goes to execute the result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff)
 command.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is not hanging on GetString(), look at the debugger's Call Stack window.  You cannot use Read() in a GUI program, it will hang your user interface until *something* is received.  Either use BeginRead() or run this code on a worker thread.

Comment: Alright, @HansPassant, that makes sense but isn't something being received? The stream should be returning something along the lines of

Comment: "HOST>" right? That means that there is something being received?

Comment: Perhaps.  But you already swallowed that with your Expect(">") call.  What comes next surely depends on what you send.  Don't stop programming too soon.

Comment: Well, not necessarily fixed it, but pointed me in the right direction.